# JavaScript Array join() cause null (%00) character in result

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ascii

I'm trying to put watermark in js file requests through RequireJs:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '/app',
    urlArgs:  [98, 121, 65, 68, 77].map(String.fromCharCode).join('')+'&v=1.0.0'
});
```

For some reasons i cannot put `byADM` directly, so i wrote above code.
My problem is after joining characters it shows `b%00%00y%01%00A%02%00D%03%00M%04%00&v=1.0.0` instead of `byADM&v=1.0.0` in the url. it's look like `''` convert to `%00`.
What can i do to get ride of this?
Is there any real empty character in String library or something else ?

Comment: Tested your code in console, works fine. Do you get right results when you just `map`,`join`,`+` ?

Comment: @Georgy Yes, in the console its Ok, but i said my problem is when this string goes in url.

Comment: @Georgy: It _looks_ fine, because you don’t see those characters/byte values when using console.log. Apply encodeURIComponent first, and you’ll see them show up.

Comment: Your code is being escaped. `unescape('b%00%00y%01%00A%02%00D%03%00M%04%00&v=1.0.0')` will  return `byADM&v=1.0.0 correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype.map` passes **three arguments** to the callback: `currentValue`, `index`, `array`. `String.fromCharCode` accepts any number of arguments, converting them all in one go. Essentially you are calling `String.fromCharCode(98, 0, [])` by passing `String.fromCharCode` directly as callback to `map`.

You'll need to cull the additional arguments:

```
[98, 121, 65, 68, 77].map((c) => String.fromCharCode(c))
```

But, rather than fighting this behaviour, you can also use `String.fromCharCode`'s ability to accept any number of arguments to simplify your code:

```
String.fromCharCode.apply(String, [98, 121, 65, 68, 77]) + '&v=1.0.0'
```

Or, you know…

```
String.fromCharCode(98, 121, 65, 68, 77) + '&v=1.0.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for completing @CBroe answere.

Comment: That’s the better answer, I think. I suspected it had something to do with the parameters passed to the callback function, but didn’t go look it up in detail. @MeTe-30, you should probably accept this one.

Comment: @MeTe-30 *facepalm* There's actually a much better solution… See update.

Comment: thanks! that's so much close to my minimalist personality!

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know why exactly, but it looks like you need to wrap String.formCharCode into an additional anonymous function:

```
urlArgs:  [98, 121, 65, 68, 77].map(
  function(c) {
    return String.fromCharCode(c);
  }
).join('')+'&v=1.0.0'
```